# Concatenar Pseudoclases y selectores de atributo - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas, quizá esté haciendo una burrada como un piano de cola, pero estoy tratando de alcanzar, de un listado que creo con muchos DIV, un elemento muy en concreto.

Actualmente, lo que estoy haciendo es ésto, pero no me lo reconoce:

```
var i = $('#listado_facturas div:nth-child(10)[data-visible="yes"]').data('item')===0?0:1;
```

Para resumir, que no se si se entiende muy bien lo que quiero, quiero alcanzar el DIV hijo número 10 que contenga un atributo "Data-Visible" igual a YES.

Cuando le hago el console.log, no me reconoce el elemento que estoy tratando de alcanzar. Y esta es la única manera que se me ocurre. Porque alcanzarlo por ID no me es posible, la posición del ID puede cambiar en cada momento que haga una operación.

Desconozco si ésto se puede hacer o estoy haciendo una burrada terrible. Cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta buscando todos elementos #10 y luego preguntar si el elemento tiene el atributo data-`visible="yes"` utilizando la funcion `each()`:

```js
var div = $('#listado_facturas div:nth-child(10)');

console.log(div.length);

var dataVisibleDiv = [];
//recoremos cada elemento y verificamos que tenga el attributo
div.each(function(_, element){

   if($(element).data("visible") == "yes") {
     console.log("Contiene atributo");
     dataVisibleDiv.push(element);
   }
});

console.log("cantidad elemento con data-visible:" + dataVisibleDiv.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="listado_facturas">

 <div>div 1</div>
 <div>div 2</div>
 <div>div 3</div>
 <div>div 4</div>
 <div>div 5</div>
 <div>div 6</div>
 <div>div 7</div>
 <div>div 8</div>
 <div>div 9</div>
 <div data-visible='yes'>div 10<iv>
 <div>div 1</div>
 <div>div 2</div>
 <div>div 3</div>
 <div>div 4</div>
 <div>div 5</div>
 <div>div 6</div>
 <div>div 7</div>
 <div>div 8</div>
 <div>div 9</div>
 <div data-visible='yes'>div 10<iv>
  <div>div 1</div>
 <div>div 2</div>
 <div>div 3</div>
 <div>div 4</div>
 <div>div 5</div>
 <div>div 6</div>
 <div>div 7</div>
 <div>div 8</div>
 <div>div 9</div>
 <div>div 10<iv>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Efectivamente, esto sería una opción, pero me veo obligado a recorrer con un bucle todos los elementos, porque como digo, no necesariamente va a ser el 10º div de los que haya creados, si no el 10º div que tenga el data-visible. Ya se que lo que pido lo hace ya la máquina buceando por el DOM, pero no se si hay alguna manera de hacerlo como digo yo.

Comment: A claremos algo. Buscas el elemento 10º de una larga lista o buscas el elemento que tenga el atributo `data-visible`?

Comment: Busco el elemento 10 de una larga lista QUE CONTENGA el atributo data-visible == yes. Es decir, que habrá 9 elementos antes que tengan dicho elemento también.

Comment: Pero vamos, casi ya la pregunta es si se pueden utilizar los selectores así, ya que estoy viendo que voy a afrontar el código de otra manera, porque si no, recargaré mucho el DOM. No obstante, ya me resultaría interesante saber si esto que estoy tratando de hacer, se puede

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada y dime  era eso lo que buscabas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirve como punto de apoyo para solucionarlo. :D